# spark scala datastax csv load file and print schema

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, datastax

Spark version 2.0.2.6
Scala version 2.11.11
Using DataStax 5.0

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import java.util.Calendar
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object csvtocassandra {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val key_space = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please enter cassandra Key Space Name: ")
    val table_name = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please enter cassandra Table Name: ")

    // Cassandra Part

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sample1").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    println(Calendar.getInstance.getTime)

    // Scala Read CSV Part
    val spark1 = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().master("local").config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()

    val csv_input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please enter csv file location: ")
    val df_csv = spark1.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferschema", "true").load(csv_input)

    df_csv.printSchema()
    }
    }
```

Why am I not able to run this program as a Job trying to submit it to spark. When I run this program using IntelliJ it works. 
But When I create a JAR and run it I am getting following Error.

Command:

```
> dse spark-submit --class "csvtospark" /Users/del/target/scala-2.11/csvtospark_2.11-1.0.jar
```

I am getting following Error:

```
ERROR 2017-11-02 11:46:10,245 org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper: Failed to start or submit Spark application
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dsefs://127.0.0.1/Users/Desktop/csv/example.csv;
```

Why is it appending dsefs://127.0.0.1 part even though I am giving just the path /Users/Desktop/csv/example.csv when asked.

I tried giving --mater option as well. How ever I am getting the same error. I am running DataStax Spark in Local Machine. No Cluster.
Please correct me where I am doing things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Never mind. Sorry about that.

input should be file:///file_name